# Failed to determine whether /sys is a mount point: Bad file descriptor

Tags: xen

I have an old Xen machine that got hard rebooted. All of the guest domains recovered, except one (the important one, of course). This is what I get when I try to boot that domain:

```
[    0.486626] xvda2: detected capacity change from 0 to 1073741824
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
[    0.782231] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    1.045040] systemd[1]: Failed to determine whether /sys is a mount point: Bad file descriptor
[    1.045072] systemd[1]: Failed to determine whether /proc is a mount point: Bad file descriptor
[    1.045091] systemd[1]: Failed to determine whether /dev is a mount point: Bad file descriptor
[!!!!!!] Failed to mount early API filesystems, freezing.
[    1.046082] systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

I understand vaguely what it's saying: there's a problem with /sys, /proc, or /dev and so the VM can't boot.

However, in dom0 I can `mount disk.img /mnt` and browse all the contents, including those special directories.

I've tried using `losetup` to set up a loopback device to `disk.img`, and I `fsck -f` that device with no errors.

If this were a physical machine, I'd probably try booting into single user mode and examining the "physical" disk devices using `fsck`, but I'm not sure how to do that with Xen involved.

What am I missing here? What should I try next?

Comment: [unix.SE] or possibly serverfault.com might have better insight and expertise on this.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks for the suggestion. Is there an easy way to migrate the question, or do I just make a new question on the other site?

Comment: No problem. it doesn't look like I can automigrate to either of the sites I mentioned.  You can just go ahead and make the new question on the other site.